# Angular - alert() executes before view change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

Why is it that alert() executes before the change in the view? And how can it be achieved that the view is changed, and **then** the alert pops up?

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.points = 0;
  $scope.add = function() {
    ++$scope.points;
    alert('This alert appears before the score is changed in the view')
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p ng-click="add()">
    Score: {{ points }}
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on how browser works. The view will `rerender` only after event has finished but the data has already been changed.

refer the below example I entirely copied from you, except that I add one row `console.log`. You can confirm by open browser's console to see what happened.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.points = 0;
  $scope.add = function() {
    ++$scope.points;
    console.log($scope.points);    // open browser to confirm
    alert('This alert appears before the score is changed in the view')
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p ng-click="add()">
    Score: {{ points }}
  </p>
</div>
```

---

Normal case without angularjs

```js
function showAlert() {
  document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = '1111';
  alert('Information changed');
}
```

```html
<span id="show"></span>
<input type="text" onchange="showAlert()">
```

---

the tricky example I commented using `$timeout`

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.points = 0;
  $scope.add = function() {
    ++$scope.points;
    console.log($scope.points);    // open browser to confirm
    
    $timeout(function() {
      alert('This alert appears before the score is changed in the view');
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p ng-click="add()">
    Score: {{ points }}
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok I totally get that, but how can it be achieved that the view changes, and then the alert() is shown?

Comment: @JoseMendez for what I know, It's not possible. But you can try with `$timeout` to add another task(showing alert) to scheduler which looks strange and somehow tricky.

Comment: @JoseMendez with `$timeout` will let the event finished first and rerender the view, then the scheduler($timeout) will run to show the `alert`.

Comment: The $timeout option works, but it introduced 4 weird behvaviors in the real application I'm building. Completely at a loss why... I tried it before asking the question, which is one of the strange behaviors I mentioned. I did not work at that time. I see it working on Pengyy's code so, it definitely works. It is probably my code that contains the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `digest` cycle isn't completed before moving to the `alert()` code. One option would be to wrap your `alert` in a timeout

```
 setTimeout(function() {
     alert('This alert appears before the score is changed in the view')
 },1);
```

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.points = 0;
  $scope.add = function() {
    ++$scope.points;
    setTimeout(function() {
     alert('This alert appears before the score is changed in the view')
    },1);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p ng-click="add()">
    Score: {{ points }}
  </p>
</div>
```